# Startx failing in FreeBSD

Tags: xorg, gnome, freebsd

I've install gnome2, xorg, and xinit (should xorg have done that for me?), and startx yields:

"xinit: unable to run server "/usr/local/bin/X": No such file or directory"
I checked in the directory, and startx, xpath, and xinit are all there
Am I still missing dependencies? If so, which ones?

Both the gnome2 and x11 installations took a lifetime and a half so I thought they got everything...

Comment: Do you have an executable `/usr/local/bin/X`? Most probably your system's is called `/usr/bin/X`...

Comment: are you using [t]csh ? did you run rehash after installing?

Comment: How did you go about installing xorg?  It sounds like many components are missing.  Did you use packages or the port?  If the port, I'd go to /usr/ports/x11/xorg and make depends to verify everything was built.  To fix this particular error, you could install the xorg-server package or find the port in /usr/ports/x11-servers/xorg-server

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have had to install xinit, as installing xorg should have done that for you.

I would suspect that xorg didn't install correctly. **I would delete and reinstall xorg**; It's a meta-port, meaning that it doesn't install anything for itself, but pulls in a load of dependencies which essentially contain what you need. One of those dependencies is `/usr/local/bin/X` (pointing to `/usr/local/bin/Xorg`).

It's worth mentioning that the package to installed is actually called just **xorg** - not xorg-server or anything.